# Fingering for piano arpeggio

Tags: piano, technique, fingering

What would be a good piano fingering for these left hand arpeggios? They are played fast. I don't know if it is better to play 531-5321 or 531-5312? We only have F#.

[image: How to play]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what # or b are involved. On the assumption none, then they're probably easiest rolled, so keep the same fingering for the outside notes, leaving index to play the extra. If, as I suspect, it's G# on top, then the same applies.

However - it's you that's playing, so only you can really decide. That's part of the 'fun' of playing something new. Working out what best fits *your* hand. Sometimes there's no best, but it's worth considering what's happening in the next bar. perhaps your hand needs to go down again, perhaps up beyond those notes. It's an important criterion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot to mention that we have #F. So the notes here are all white keys. I had a feeling that it is easier for the brain to handle the same fingering for the outside notes, when played fast.

Answer (score 1):

I would play it as 531-5421. Because these are dotted half notes, you should have enough time to switch. If however, these were arpeggiated eighth notes, then I'd keep the common fingers and go for a more awkward (at least for me) 541-5421.

Answer (score 1):

And, I would play it 531-5321. Which goes to show you that it's as Tim says: different people use different fingerings for the same passage.